# Setting font and font-size of title bar text in a UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a simple navigation based application for the iphone/objective-c

within various UIViewControllers that are pushed into view, I can set the text in the title bar using something like

```
self.title = @"blah blah blah"
```

Is there a way to control the **font** and **font-size** of the title in the title bar text?

thanks!

Answer (score 17):

the proper way to resize the title text of a navcontroller is to set the titleView property of the navigationItem

like this (in viewDidLoad)

```
   UILabel* tlabel=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 40)];
        tlabel.text=self.navigationItem.title;
    tlabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    tlabel.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    tlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    self.navigationItem.titleView=tlabel;
```

Answer (score 5):

You may want to emboss the label so it doesn't look fuzzy and flat:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 44);
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = self.navigationItem.title;
    // emboss so that the label looks OK
    [label setShadowColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
    [label setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -0.5)];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what FontHelper is, so I used:  `label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];`   This seems pretty close to the original font for the nav bar title.

Comment: @Ginny - sorry about that, I didn't notice that I'd left in a call to my own FontHelper class!

Answer (score 4):

IF you want this to work both on iphone and ipad, and also want to get the title centered then use the following code.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel* label=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.navigationItem.titleView.frame.size.width, 40)];
    label.text=self.navigationItem.title;
    label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    label.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    label.font = [AppHelper titleFont];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.navigationItem.titleView=label;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can assign any UIView to a navcontroller's title area.

Create a `UILabel` and set its font and size anyway you want, then assign it to the UIViewController's `navigationItem.titleView` property. Make sure the UILabel's backgroundColor is set to clearColor.

This only works on the top-level nav-view. As the user drills down into the view controller hierarchy and the "back" button is shown the alternate titleView is ignored and the regular text label is shown.

Comment: Is there any way to set the font-size etc. for the *drill-down* title bars?

Comment: The official docs say drill-down titleviews are ignored (presumably because they want the user to see the text before it shows up in the 'back' button of the next level down.) But you can always try overriding viewDidLoad and recursively scanning down the view hierarchy of the NavBar until you find the right UILabel then set the font on that.